Does replacing 'but' with 'and' change the meaning?
From Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.602.
Preposition stranding is restricted to various kinds of non-canonical construction such as open interrogatives, relatives, etc.: in canonical con-structions traditional prepositions (with the minor exception of the notwithstanding type) always do precede their complements. But so do verbs, adjectives, and adverbs.
Can we here replace 'but' with 'and'? Now that we've used 'so do', why not use'and'?

And is not necessary; so do is enough to indicate that verbs, adjectives and adverbs also precede their complements.
The reason for including but is to remind the reader that 'preceding their complements' is not something that is unique to 'traditional prepositions'.

I didn't get that question right - but neither did most of my classmates.

